# How can I apply ansi-color to complete buffer?

Tags: region, minor-mode, commands, coloring, ansi

I am using following code to apply colorize text in emacs, such as for `^[` characters to apply color. In order to use this code I have to select text to apply it

reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19505/198423

```lisp
(defun ansi-color-apply-on-region-int (beg end)
  "interactive version of func"
  (interactive "r")
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region beg end))
```

How can I automatically apply it for the complete buffer? Is there any alternative solution to use it as a mode something like `ansi-color-mode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that function does what you want on the region then this should do what you want on the entire buffer:

```lisp
(ansi-color-apply-on-region-int (point-min) (point-max))
```

If you want to do it interactively then `C-x h` followed by `M-x ansi-color-apply-on-region-int`.

Or use this command:

```lisp
(defun ansi-color-on-buffer ()
  "..."
  (interactive)
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max)))
```

If the buffer is narrowed, that acts on the visible portion. If you instead want to act on the full buffer, even if it's narrowed, then change `(point-min)` to `1` and `(point-max)` to `(buffer-size)`.

If you want a minor mode:

```lisp
(define-minor-mode ansi-color-mode 
  "..."
  nil nil nil
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region 1 (buffer-size)))
```

Replace the `"..."` occurrences with doc strings that say what each function does. See the Elisp manual, node [Function Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Documentation.html) for info about writing doc strings for functions.

Comment: Can `"..."` remain or should I replace it with some other valid string?

Comment: Yes, replace it with a doc string that describes what the minor mode does - what it's for. I updated the answer with some info about writing doc strings.

Comment: would it be possible to change themes for the `ansi-color-mode`, such as can I apply https://github.com/dracula/emacs ? I can ask different question since it is not related

Comment: Please ask a different question for that. (And I have no idea about that. Hopefully someone else will be able to help.)